# Why UDP socket doesn't receive udp traffic from nc -u host port?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, netcat

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     struct sockaddr_in src = { .sin_family=AF_INET, .sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY, .sin_port=htons(90) };

     int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

     bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src, sizeof(src));

     char buf[1024];
     ssize_t res = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, 0);
     printf("res=%zi\n", res);

     return 0;
 }
```

After compiling and execute this program. On another terminal I execute

```
nc -u localhost 90
```

to test if I'm actually receiving some udp traffic from "any interface" as I would expect since I've used INADDR_ANY. But the programs just hangs. What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me if the server can actually bind to the port (i.e. don't ignore errors) and `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` and not `::1`.

Comment: What is the res value in your case?

Comment: *bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src, sizeof(src));*?!?!  There's a reason why library functions such as `bind()` actually return a value that indicates success or failure...

Comment: @Maicake: *"What is the res value in your case?"* - the number of bytes I've send using `nc -u` - as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't providing enough data through `nc`.
I was facing two situation:

```
nc -u localhost 1025
```

The program was hanging....obviously because I didn't pass nothing except from `'\n'` which wasn't received by the socket.

```
nc -u -v localhost 1025
```

I was still passing just `'\n'` but in this case the socket was receiving it.

Writing a bunch of characters worked in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

port 90 is less than 1024 so a process requires privileges in order to bind a socket to it.

You have two options:

1. choose a port above 1024
2. run your program with privileges (sudo...)

One should consider testing the result of `bind()` (as any other system call in general) to easily detect such situations.

Comment: Thanks, but it still keep hanging at the recvfrom call. I've tried to use 1025 and also to run it using sudo.

Comment: @Maicake If you use, from another terminal, `netstat -panu` while your program is running, do you see it bound to the port you chose?

Comment: yes, anyway there is a strange behaviour.
If you try nc -u localhost 1025  it doesn't receive the packet. If you try nc -u -v localhost 1025 it works. But really I can't understand why since -v is just to have verbose nc output

Comment: Anyway res is 1 so I don't think it works correctly.

Comment: @Maicake when `res` is `1` what do you enter on the `nc` side?

Comment: @Maicake yes, but once `nc -u localhost 1025` is running, do you actually provide more than 1 character `'\n'` in its standard input? When I test your program (with 1025) `res` matches exactly the length of the input in `nc`.

Comment: damn. I wasn't providing more characters and with nc -u -v  it was receiving also just the \n  but no with nc -u . Thanks